# Map only displays last logged annotation

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database that stores latitude and longitude coordinates which I use to place pins on a map the only problem is when I look at the map it only ever shows me the last recorded entry. When I check my Database I currently have 226 entries but they do not show up.  Here is my function I've created that I call in ViewDidLoad:

```
func displayAnnotations() {

        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("Postbox").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let monToFri = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!["Monday to Friday Collection Time"] as! String?
            let sat = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!["Saturday Collection Time"] as! String?
            let latitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!["Latitude"] as! String?
            let longitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!["Longitude"] as! String?

            let lastCollection = "Mon - Fri: \(monToFri!)" + " Sat:  \(sat!)"

            self.annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (Double(latitude!))!, longitude: (Double(longitude!))!)
            self.annotation.title = "Last Collection:"
            self.annotation.subtitle = lastCollection

            self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.annotation)

            self.postboxesLoggedLabel.text = String(self.mapView.annotations.count)

        })

    }
```

[image: Database Structure]

Comment: What does your database structure look like?  Where are the map items that you're expecting to receive?

Comment: Hi Doug I know the structure is fine as my AppStore version is working perfectly, I went to make edits without backing up my code and I've broke it and can't figure out how? I'm assuming I need a loop to display them all rather than just the last one?

Comment: Yes you will need a for loop. I usually have an array of annotations and use array.count for the length then addAnnotation() to maView within the loop. It looks like you are just adding one or overwriting them.

Comment: Did you check if your `with: { (snapshot) in` gets called multiple times? Running it in a debugger and setting a breakpoint inside the closure might be the easiest way to determine whether the problem is in the loading from the database, or if it's in adding it to the map.

Comment: I’m 99% sure this a loop problem but can’t figure how to loop through the database on firebase

Answer (score 1):

The code is using .childAdded which iterates over each child once and then any time a child is added after that - so it already 'loops' through the child nodes.

The first problem I see is that you're overwriting self.annotation each time a child is loaded, and it appears to be a class var which is unneeded. That results in self.annotation only ever containing the last node read from Firbase.

You should really create a new annotation object for each child and add it to your dataSource array.

Secondly, there doesn't appear to be any kind of refresh so once all of the nodes are loaded into your dataSource it's not updating the mapView or whatever you are using.

Here's one possible solution (out of many)

```
//define a class to hold the firebase data
class AnnotationClass {
    var key = ""
    var lat = ""
    var lon = ""
    var collTimeMF = ""
    var collTimeS = ""

    convenience init(fromSnapshot snap: DataSnapshot) {
        self.init()
        self.key = snap.key

        if let dict = snap.value as? [String: Any] {
            self.lat = dict["latitude"] as? String ?? ""
            self.lon = dict["longitude"] as? String ?? ""
            self.collTimeMF = dict["MF"] as? String ?? ""
            self.collTimeS = dict["Sat"] as? String ? ""
        }
    }
}

//a class var array to hold all of the annotations
var annotationArray = [AnnotationClass]()

//the function to read in all of the firebase nodes, populate array, update map
func displayAnnotations() {
    let postBoxRef = self.ref.child("Postbox") //self.ref points to my Firebase
    postBoxRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        let a = AnnotationClass(fromSnapshot: snapshot)
        self.annotationArray.append(a)

        //update map
    })
}
```

There are a couple of issues with this code which may/may not be an issue for this use case. As you can see the map is being updated with each child node. If it's only a few that's no big deal. If it's a LOT then it could cause flicker.

In that case, you may want to consider loading by .observeSingleEvent by .value which will enable the dataSource array to be populated with all of the data at once (by iterating over the returned snapshot child nodes) and once that's complete update the map.

Note there's no real error checking in this code so please add some.